# Interpret 32 bits as Integer in python

Tags: python, type-conversion, byte, bit

I read bits from a file.
The first value is

```
bits = str(11101111010110011000000000000001)
```

This is the binary representation of a signed 32 bit integer so this is already in two's complement and little endian.
I think the value I want to get is

-279347199

atleast this website converts it as such http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?hexadecimal=EF598001

everything I found that solves this problem interprets the bits as pure binary without two's complement and little endian

Comment: What do you mean by little endian? Endianness is related to the order of **bytes** in **memory**. And you have characters representing bits in a string. If I extrapolate your analogy, the left most bit (with he lowest address), should be the least significant bit, in which case your conversion is false. Can you clarify?

Comment: Like I said I'm not entirely sure I get these bits from a file. I was told that if the value is interpreted as float it's -6*e²⁸ and this website returns the same value http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=EF598001. But the float values don't really make sense and I was told maybe you have tio interpret them as integers, so I guessed that the integer values are also correct on this website but i'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

A neat trick to convert from two's complement is to find 1 from the end and replace rest of the bits by their complement.

```
def convert_from_twosc(bits):
    bits = bits[::-1]
    for bit in bits:
        if bit == '1':
            for new_bit in range(bits.index(bit) + 1, len(bits)):
                if bits[new_bit] == '0':
                    bits[new_bit] = '1'
                else:
                    bits[new_bit] = '0'
            break
    return "".join(map(str, bits[::-1]))
bits = input()
number = int(convert_from_twosc(list(bits)) , 2) * -1
print(number)
```

Output:

```
11101111010110011000000000000001
-279347199
```

This function always assumes input to it, is a signed negative number so be careful.